# C# skipping if not null

Tags: c#, winforms, int

I have a click event handler which has to check if two text boxes are null or not, if both aren't the values are given to two variables and passed to another method.

One variable is a String, the other an integer. If the String is null but the integer isn't, it will work fine(Which it shouldn't!). But, if the integer is null and the String isn't, it will give me an error which is expected because it should not have reached that point.

Here's the code:

```
        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ActorName;
        int Position;
        if ((txtPosition.Text != null))
        {
            if ((txtActorName.Text != null))
            {
                ActorName = txtActorName.Text;
                Position = int.Parse(txtPosition.Text);
                InsertIntoArrayList(ActorName, Position);
                PopulateActors();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter an Actor Name");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a position");
            return;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, if txtPosition is not null, it then tests txtActorName. If either are null, it throws the relevant message. Assuming both are not null, it assigns the values to the variables and passes these to the InsertIntoArrayLIst method, followed by a call to the PopulateActors method.

If I enter an Actor name and a position, everything works fine. It's only if I don't enter a position that it somehow misses the fact that nothings entered, then slips up at the line `Position = int.Parse(txtPosition.Text);` because txtPosition is null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: not empty =/= not null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using e.g. `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPosition.Text)` instead of `txtPosition.Text != null`.

Alternatively, just use `txtPosition.Text != ""`. After all, the Text property should never actually be null.

And of course, you should apply the same fix to both values, txtPosition and txtActor.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something simple! Thank you Peter.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't confuse `null` and empty strings. They aren't the same thing.
2. The `Text` property of any control will only ever be `null` if you explicitly set it to null. In most cases you don't need to check this at all for that property; just comparing to an empty string is good enough
3. The `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` and `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()` methods are your friends.
4. There's no reason to nest the `If` blocks. Just use guard clauses to check one followed by the other for cleaner code:

.

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtPosition.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a position");
        return; 
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtActorName.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an Actor Name");
        return;
    }
    int Position;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtPosition.Text, out Position))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the position field");
        return;
    }

    InsertIntoArrayList(txtActorName.Text, Position);
    PopulateActors();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPosition.Text)` if you want to check for white spaces as well. Although performance wise it is a bit slower then using the standard `string.IsNullOrEmtpy`

`if (txtPosition.Text != string.Empty)` is another way to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, it may resolve your Problem

ActorName = txtActorName.Text;

Position = int.Parse(txtPosition.Text=="" ? "0" : txtPosition.Text);